# Links nofollow and dofollow on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, seo

How does Stack Overflow use `nofollow` and `dofollow` on links in questions and answers?

I really don't understand how the website selects what links are marked `nofollow`. Is it based on

- Age of the user account?
- Pertinents links?

See this example:

[How to use joda time with JPA (eclipselink)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783577/how-to-use-joda-time-with-jpa-eclipselink/9788903#9788903)

[The JPA hashCode() / equals() dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031614/the-jpa-hashcode-equals-dilemma?rq=1)

[php order array in two ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706873/php-order-array-in-two-ways?rq=1)

Comment: Might be based on the rep of the poster. The `nofollow` on the website link in profile is removed at 2k rep I believe, so others may work in a similar way.

Comment: Quick guess: internal vs. external links. *post here* links to a Stack Exchange site post..

Comment: Rather than a screenshot, can you give us a link to the actual post?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Check somes questions on Stack Overflow, there is external links on Dofollow

Comment: @Ricoxor: Why not give us those examples in your post here?

Answer (score 38):

From [Geoff Dalgas on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111279/remove-nofollow-on-links-deemed-reputable):

> This is a followup to the following meta post:
>
> [Remove nofollow on links at a certain age](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51136/remove-nofollow-on-links-at-a-certain-age/51156#51156)
>
> We have been in contact with [Matt Cutts](http://www.mattcutts.com) regarding removing
>   nofollow:
>
> > ... we’re trying to encourage sites with valuable user-generated content
> >     (like Stack Exchange) to have a more nuanced approach to the nofollow
> >     attribute on user-generated links. Using the attribute on all
> >     user-generated links takes away a big incentive from spammers, and
> >     prevents spammy links from being included in search ranking. However,
> >     good links can also be made invisible to search engines with this
> >     policy, so we miss out on that ranking signal, which could be used to
> >     surface better or fresher high-quality content that your users are
> >     recommending.
>
> Starting today we will be removing nofollow on links within posts that
>   hit a high enough threshold to be considered reputable.  The details
>   will remain somewhat vague at the moment to discourage gaming of this
>   feature.

So, not publicly disclosed.

Answer (score 4):

You need to earn 2000 points for the rel="nofollow" restriction for your website link to be lifted.
If that same link is there on your about page, it won't get nofollow either.

Comment: I have 2000+ reputation, but still my most of the links are no-follow, Please check my answer here, the link is no-follow
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61469462/5701085