# A step towards stopping spammers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As the SE site is growing with number of users, spammers are also increasing. [Smokey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3735529/smokedetector) is doing a good job in detecting the *possible* spam posts and posting the link in the following chat rooms where active users can assess and flag the posts if necessary.

- [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)
- [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq)
- [Tavern On The Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)

**About spam posts:**

From my observations in the last few months I noticed:

1. Spammers are new users having reputation 1.
2. The format of spam is the same:

   ```
    Some product/service information
    ...

    website Link
    phone number
   ```

   The phone number is not always included, but the link is always present.
3. Spammers use tags that have low traffic (for example, [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file)), making the spam survive a longer time.

**What can SE/SO do?**

**Add a minimum reputation restriction (*something like 5/10 which could be very easy to get for a legit user*) to add external links** and optionally allowing only some selected white-listed sites that are related to programming, providing live demos. Some examples could be [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/), [regex101](https://regex101.com/), etc.

Comment: I'm not against this idea, but I probably wouldn't bother to whitelist those particular sites. The odds of them being used correctly by a 1-rep user seem pretty low to me.

Comment: Make new users wait for 24 hours before they can ask their first question.  Not just good to slow down spam btw.

Comment: @HansPassant Why user has to wait? I'm just suggesting not to allow external site links in the post.

Comment: I'd extend that further. I would say posting links should require the same rep as commenting. Links in decent answers are never essential, so it wouldn't hurt to not have them asap.

Comment: @BilltheLizard If the new user wants to answer and want to add external demo site link provided user don't know about stack-snippet editor, white-listed sites is good choice.

Comment: To slow them down of course.  Spammers have no patience, they can only survive by spamming at a high rate.

Comment: You're right, if the intent is only to reduce spam, then whitelisting those sites certainly shouldn't hurt.  But since most 1-rep users are probably just as likely to abuse those sites (with a link-only answer, for example), it probably would't matter either way if they weren't included. If we're going to make users reach a certain reputation level before they can include links, it's probably a good idea to make them wait to use those sites too.

Comment: @HansPassant Agreed. But, this will also frustrate legit users, who want to get the answers to their questions quickly from the first question itself-that's what SO is know for. And most of the users join SO when they're having some urgent issue

Comment: Oh, giving a user a good reason to keep his SO account is most certainly *not* a problem.   SO is not the right place to demand a timely response, urgent problems are always best solved by 1st party support.

Comment: This could also help cut down on users who link to screenshots of code/errors.  There is a minimum rep involved with embedding images, and users often bypass this by just linking to the image.

Comment: @cimmanon I really don't see a problem with users giving a link to an image. I usually click the links to see if it's legit and I edit the answer embedding the image. Though I have no idea if this is good practice or not.

Comment: @KФ Ordinary images (such as an illustration of a layout problem) are fine, screenshots of code are not fine.

Comment: @HansPassant: Programming a incubation period into a spambot is a trivial task...

Comment: SO users can always beat any bot that can only create one post every 24 hours.  It is trivial.

Comment: that sounds like a neat heuristics to push the question into [meta-tag:triage] queue. I just checked, spam mark is on top in the list displayed when one clicks "Unsalvageable"

Comment: What problem is this suggeston fixing? Is spam this big a problem that it warrants this change?

Comment: Spam seems to get handled pretty quickly, i almost never actually see it on stackoverflow.

Comment: I have seen spam from existing users with multiple answers and rep > 1, so there goes your first criterion out the window.

Comment: As the users have said below, the more restrictions you add, the more restrictions the spammers learn to work around. They aren't ever going to stop spamming, so the best way is to get them to waste their time posting spam which is subsequently removed.

Comment: @Hans: _"SO users can always beat any bot that can only create one post every 24 hours"_ -- a 24 hour waiting period doesn't equate to "can only create one post every 24 hours". It just makes the spam pipeline 24 hours deep; i.e. it will delay spam for a _single_ 24 hour period (right after the policy is instituted), and then the spam bots are back in business with new spam every day. They just have to use the accounts they created yesterday for the purpose.

Comment: Do you guys at least blacklist the domain names linked with the spam?

Comment: @BilltheLizard "The odds of them being used correctly by a 1-rep user seem pretty low to me." -- Everybody's gotta start somewhere...

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Yes, and posting a link-only question or answer isn't the place to start. We should be encouraging new users to post their full question or answer here, instead of posting their code on another site. As I said, though, that isn't the point of this question. I'm thinking a step ahead in considering what else a URL whitelist could be used for, so it probably should be brought up in a separate question if this idea gets traction.

Comment: Should this question be on meta.stackexchange instead of meta.stackoverflow?

Comment: No one else noticed the tongue twister in the question title?

Comment: This might be a good idea for other reasons, but it won't do anything to 'stop' spammers. I've seen a heck of a lot of spam evolve over and over again to match our defenses - they'll just start posting links in code blocks or something. Spam really isn't a huge problem here; it gets dealt with quickly. Imposing this won't really do anything to spammers.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Don't get me wrong when I say this, but spam will come, whether we like it or not. Spammers will always find a way: posting a good answer before spamming, to editing after an approved first post, to even circumventing IP blocks.

> Spammers are new users having reputation 1.

I've seen instances of spam that have come from users who have gotten the association bonus. (At least on the site where I moderate, [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com).

> The format of spam is the same...

Ummm... Not really. Spam has taken many forms: not all spam has to take that form: and once spammers learn that this "form" is blocked, they'll find ways to get around it. It's a short-term solution, let's discourage that.

> Spammers use tags that have low traffic (for example, batch-file), making the spam survive a longer time.

This doesn't really bug me. Less people see it, and if they do, they can still flag as spam, or anything. Remember, that every new post will go through a queue: whether it's in the First Posts, or the Low Quality Posts, it will be seen by at least a few people. (If something sneaks through that, then it's an issue with the reviewers, which we don't need to argue about right now.

> Add a minimum reputation restriction (something like 5/10 which could be very easy to get for a legit user) to add external links and optionally allowing only some selected white-listed sites...

Who will maintain such a white-list? What if a user tries genuinely linking to a news article, or to a site for documentation? People will get pretty mad if we can't let them ask a question.

---

In response to comments, and other answers:

New users are already faced with many restrictions, including one that limits the number of links they can place in a post. I don't see why we need another. We also don't need to add extra steps to "approve" various parts in a post. How will we know whether or not to add these steps to a queue?

The system works well: 6 spam flags and a post is out. The spam blocking system learns to be wary of that content and address.

Comment: The association bonus shouldn't matter if you look for the first post by users on that particular stack exchange site.

Comment: Which proves my response to the third quote: That the post will be seen (In the instance that I referenced, the First Post got invalidated - likely because it got deleted before the review could be completed)

Comment: "I've seen instances of spam that have come from users who have gotten the association bonus." That sounds like an outlier. "Who will maintain such a whitelist?" Don't we have huge sites with links we already allow? "Less people see it, and if they do, they can still flag as spam, or anything." I think they're also trying to SEO. If Google sees it before we delete it, they win. Let's keep raising the bar here.

Comment: @AaronHall Links by new users can't get SEO because of the no follow attribute. What huge sites do we allow? I've never heard this. Trust me - the amount of spam that comes from users with rep shouldn't be neglected.

Comment: "What huge sites do we allow?" We *have* huge sites that we actively maintain, with loads of links in their content - they are great sources with which to start for whitelists. - On the whole, I don't think your objections are very strong. Perhaps they're made with your SE site in mind. If that's the case, maybe you could have a lower bar on Open Source. I *strongly* support raising the bar on the StackOverflow site.

Answer (score 12):

> Spammers are new users having reputation 1

Which would lead to believe their first post would be their spam question. If so then it should be covered in the "first posts" section under review. No?

That being said I would like to point out that as a new user you already have quite a bit of restrictions, even if 5/10 rep is easy to get.

If spamming really is becoming a problem as SO/SE expands, then why not just disable links (= links that are greyed out and upon click do not open a new tab), until they've been approved by a higher rep user?

An option can be added in the First Posts section under Review and on the Post itself to approve or disapprove of this link.

Seeing that the First Posts section under Review is almost always at 0, they should be covered quickly.

[image: first posts]

I'd also like to point out that if we do not allow external links, I'm pretty sure we'll be seeing these kind of links: www[dot]myspamwebsite[dot][com]

Comment: While all firsts posts do get reviewed, that takes time, and that means that spam can stick around for 20 minutes until it gets the required reviews to delete it. The idea of disabling links is interesting, although reviewers not bothering to check out links (which could be malicious or otherwise evil) might be a problem.

Comment: *why not just disable links...until they've been approved by a higher rep user* - Would that scale though? Especially since many people look at Stack Overflow at work and are naturally wary of clicking on [malicious links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts). I think increasing the moderation burden should be a last resort.

Comment: @Tushar I don't think so. It's already being done in the First Post review. Notifiying people that are reviewing to approve or disapprove of links wouldn't be that much of a burden. It should be something they do already. BSMP in the end we are doing away with links all together. This way they are still here and **IF** they get *eventually* approved by a higher rep that would be a plus. Because if we remove external links all together spammers and normal new users will be forced to do things like *www[dot]mywebsite[dot]com*, and I don't think that adds a plus to SE/SO.

Comment: @Tushar if spammers are really spamming 4-5 questions in a few minutes, then a time limit forcing new users to wait 5-10 minutes after posted a question would be interesting no?

Comment: Why do we need to add to the First Posts queue? Approving links should be a part of the review itself, I don't see any reason why we need to split this up into smaller parts.

Comment: @JonasCz to further expand on the disabled link, hovering a disabled link would trigger a popup with a warning notifying the user that *This unverified external link may be unsafe.*

Comment: @Tushar, A spammer _can't_ post 4 - 5 questions in a few minutes - New users can only post one question every  hour.

Answer (score 12):

Since first post queue is almost always empty, why not **hide first posts until they're reviewed**? On many forums, one does need to wait up to 24 hours to get his first post reviewed - so people are used to this.

I am pretty sure 1-10 minutes will not be so bad for first users. It's much better than 24hour waiting someone has proposed here.

Comment: Interesting you get upvotes, when I proposed this, I got downvotes. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308481/can-first-posts-be-reviewed-before-being-becoming-visible-on-the-site

Answer (score 10):

> As the **SE** site

If this is going to be for Stack Exchange sites, not just Stack Overflow, please don't apply this to Skeptics.SE. If your question *doesn't* have a link, it's a sign the claim being investigated isn't notable, and if your answer *doesn't* have a link, it's a sign your answer isn't properly referenced.

Comment: If it was for all sites, it should be posted at http://meta.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: What? Am I still on meta.SO.SE or Skeptics? I am confused!

Answer (score 9):

> Add a minimum reputation restriction (something like 5/10 which could be very easy to get for a legit user) to add external links

Hell no!

Really good answers to valuable questions don't always contain links, but they *usually* do. Look at any of the top answers to our [highest voted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) and you'll see *multiple* links in every single one. It's moderately unusual that an answer wouldn't benefit from any documentation references, spec citations, fiddles, library links, or links to further reading. Only 2 of my 20 highest-voted answers contain no links, and most contain several; I have one highly-upvoted answer with 13 links in it.

Having a whitelist is a nice idea, but a fantasy. Here's the list of domains my top 20 answers link to:

- jsfiddle.net x2
- gent.ilcore.com
- json.org
- www.ecma-international.org
- tools.ietf.org x4
- developer.mozilla.org x5
- php.net x8
- python.org x9
- web.archive.org
- www.w3.org x4
- github.com x6
- sublime.wbond.net
- raw.githubusercontent.com
- developer.apple.com x2
- stackoverflow.com x9
- github.io x5
- readthedocs.org x3
- www.eyecon.ro
- jquery.com x3
- getbootstrap.com
- www.httpwatch.com
- developers.google.com
- docs.guzzlephp.org
- lxml.de
- www.crummy.com
- phantomjs.org
- launchpad.net

Even within my narrow areas of knowledge and interest, the stuff I need to link to is too broad and varied to realistically be whitelisted. That means imposing this kind of restriction inevitably means harming new users' ability to provide *good answers*.

And for what? We *don't have a serious spam problem*; sure, spam gets posted to the site, but it gets cleaned up extremely rapidly by the user-base. We have the tooling already that we need to combat spammers, and you're proposing another [annoying filter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments/278195) that does clear harm to people's ability to contribute to the site in order to solve a moderation problem that doesn't really exist.

Literally all that is uniquely good about Stack Overflow depends upon *trusting users* with the powers that they need - powers that it's unusual for a site to put into the hands of its user-base. Stepping away from that by denying new users one of the most basic tools needed to create a good post - the *only way* we even let them contribute in the first place - is antithetical to that, and I don't see that it solves any problem important enough to justify it.

Comment: How many new users have their first few answers end up being a "top answer"?  By the time a new user catches on to how to write a really good answer, they've earned enough reputation to post links under this proposed change.

Answer (score -10):

I would say a more optimal solution would be to disable links for "new users" as in just not allow them to be directly clickable. Drop them in an approval queue to have the links be enabled. (Something as simple as changing the anchor to `disabled-href=""` if this doesn't make sense due to this mixing with markdown, could be as simple as altering the link urls to `disabled-http://somesite.com`

People abusing text based links that require users to copy and paste or manually type in the browser will pretty much never be able to be stopped but they are unimportant. A user cannot accidentally click the link. The spam site is not getting link cred for a highly valued site linking to them.

I would say the number one most important thing is for SO to prevent spammers from getting the tremendous value of being linked to by SO.

The primary purpose is devaluing if not entirely eliminating the value of the spam. Spammers only spam where they are successful at generating money from spamming. That's why they spam, monetary gain. Remove the money and they go away.

Comment: I am not sure how removing the ability to click on a link versus having to copy and paste it prevents spammers from achieving their goal.

Comment: @JoeW next to zero users will ever manually do that. Abusing text to try to advocate the link also is highly visible as opposed to a proper markdown link across text that doesn't show the url directly.

Comment: The spam and spam link are still in the system which means that the spammer was not stopped. Just because fewer people will copy and past the link than would click it doesn't mean that it has any impact on solving the spam issue.

Comment: @JoeW incorrect. The hyperlink is not in the system. That's the entire point, text != hyperlink.

Comment: How is something spam if the link is clickable but not spam if it isn't? Either way the content is exactly the same.

Comment: Links on a new post have nofollow so spammers don't get "the tremendous value of being linked to by SO" in the SEO sense. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291005/3093387

Comment: Having an unclickable link is a horrible UX that will make SO look bad (not to mention that it'll still look like spam...just spam that doesn't work).