# Is there a way to fend off a persistent troll?

Tags: discussion, abuse

The "wingding" snowshoe troll is making regular appearances, but the frequency appears to be escalating.  The last few days, there have been a few incidents per day; today, we are already up beyond half a dozen.

Recent stats: https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?username=wingding (see also screenshot below.)

Here is a previous question from a month ago: [How come getting abusive nuked several times in a row doesn't cause a question and answer ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322202/how-come-getting-abusive-nuked-several-times-in-a-row-doesnt-cause-a-question-a)

I assume this is out of the ordinary, and that alerting admins and power users here is the right thing to do.  Could we do something more to fend off this pest?

[image: metasmoke screenshot]

Comment: My first suggestion would be to block the proxies or rate limit the same proxies, however doing so may stop legitimate users from posting.

Comment: Not sure it was a good idea to post it here -- this question is now featured on the hot meta posts list, so the troll is well-fed.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I am for open discussion, taught me about https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector :-)

Comment: Probably super-related, for abusing-side: [Should Stack Overflow be more restrictive about new user registrations?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324220/should-stack-overflow-be-more-restrictive-about-new-user-registrations)

Comment: Maybe of interest: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/191648 (<-- not actually drupal-specific)

Comment: Stop feeding the troll.

Comment: Not very clear why this is special, SO has been a frequent spammer target since its inception.  It has never been a pressing problem before, it is easy to recognize, gets handled by SO users with aplomb and never required a bot.  Recognizing the thousands of junk posts every day that disguise themselves as legitimate programmer questions, not infrequently upvoted as they travel the review queues is a far bigger problem :)

Comment: @HansPassant To my mind, there are two different problems. Spammers spam towards reaching some external goal, whereas trolls are just here because they are trolls.  The general approach to removing junk through moderation and user intervention seems to work reasonably well, but it feels unsatisfactory in this scenario.

Comment: By looking at the graph option of the search: https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?option=graphs&username=wingding You can see that he just comes and goes in waves

Comment: @HansPassant The SD Bot makes spam alot more short lived all over the network, often it lives less then 20s due to it. It also enables smaller sites to get rid of spam very quickly (many of us at charcoal have joined dozens of communities with our accounts, to destroy spam there)

Comment: Why he always type his shit into `<p></p>` tags?

Comment: WOW. Someone that posts that "quality" of spam will be not easily stopped by an IP block. That's a medal deserving troll (yes, medal in behaving like an ass).

Comment: @Boiethios Because that's how Markdown renders HTML. Metasmoke shows the rendered HTML, hence `p` tags.

Comment: Depending on the country of origin, Stack Overflow would be within its rights to contact the ISP of the offender and request that they cut service to this person for abusive behavior.

Comment: If you can track them, sure, but that means in practive only mmmmaybe North America and Western Europe. Behind proxies, it doesn't matter where in the world they are really from, because you cannot find evidence to persuade an ISP.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Trust me, all Stack Overflow moderators are well aware of this user. The community and moderators have been destroying their posts and their accounts for a little while now.

When a post is destroyed via 6 offensive flags or 1 hard moderator-imposed flag, generally an immediate IP block is placed on their known locations. The system also starts hobbling / blocking the network they are coming from in an intelligent manner.

Most trolls usually fade off pretty quickly as a result of this, because it becomes far more effort for them to find ways to work around this than it is for us to deal with them.

This user is one of the rare trolls who has enough time and motivation to keep going. So far, I've seen this user come from multiple proxy networks and what I believe to be a zombied botnet. They've worked around blacklists for the most offensive URLs they've posted (thankfully, the site no longer allows common URL shorteners).

They're persistent, but I've seen much worse post volume and content from trolls in the past, all of whom eventually gave up. Based on my experience, eventually they too will tire of this.

Comment: We've been nuking this guys posts for over a month now over at Charcoal HQ.

Comment: Also if you're interested in a complete list of this guy's posts, you can find it [here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=&username=wingding&why=&site=&feedback=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search)

Comment: @Magisch wow... that's amazing.

Comment: @Magisch: That link is already given in the question.

Comment: Just a thought.. have you checked whether they are Tor exit nodes? I had a similar issue a couple of years ago with a service I (used to) run, turns out the troll was using Tor (which resulted in me blocking all Tor exit nodes).

Comment: @cybermonkey - We can identify visits from Tor exit nodes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175170/add-possible-tor-node-indicator-to-ip-look-up although no such measure is perfect: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222386/can-se-block-actions-from-tor-exit-nodes/222394#222394 . To my knowledge, none of these have come from Tor, but from a variety of other sources. A surprisingly small number of persistent trolls / spammers use Tor, maybe because SE has effective measures for identifying and blocking malicious traffic from there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231893/135615

Comment: And don't forget: You're doing a great job here. I've never seen any of these spam posts where I came around.

Comment: Sometimes trolls gave up, on other rare occasions, mods gave up. Trust me, it's always a 2 way street.

Comment: @Telkitty Due to the *extreme* imbalance between how much work it takes to post crap and how much work it takes to delete crap, moderators generally aren't the ones to give up.

Comment: @undo There is also an extreme imbalance between the number of moderators on Stackoverflow (<70) and the number of potential trolls (>7,000,000,000). The probability of a few extremely talented trolls visiting Stackoverflow given such a huge base P(T|P) is very large. T indicates troll, P is the population. So we are asking: what is the chance of a few high capability trolls who can get around the system (say 3?) given the potential population of 7 billion people (trolls don't have to actually use Stackoverflow like regular users).

Comment: With that said, probability calculations are a lot about assumptions. This includes the probability density function of the trolls, conditional probability of the existence of highly gifted trolls given number of moderator hours, the total number of moderator hours - to name a few.

Comment: I'm now picturing Shrek with a pair of spectacles on, scribbling Bayesian analysis on a chalkboard.

Comment: Digging this post after 2 year... Thank you and all Stack Overflow moderators. And what Brad Larson said is true, they eventually gave up [before 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48008743/5958455).

Comment: Aaaaand… they are back actually. They returned today with two posts. Their profile was nuked quickly. [1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50066116#50066116) [2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50066025#50066025). So, you failed saying they will be tired :)