# Should the 10 reputation requirement to post more than 2 links apply to pictures?

Tags: discussion, reputation, external-links

I recently tried to ask a question on a new stackexchange (stats), where I don't have any reputation. I wanted to put up two pictures and a link to explain the question. I used the `ctrl + G` shortcut. When I tried to post I got the `You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links` error message (because pictures are implemented as links).

I can understand that we don't want people to spam links all over, but should this really also apply to pictures? I feel like there are a lot of questions that could use use 1 link and 2 pictures. Especially in the `stats` stackoverflow.

Comment: Spam is most certainly a concern, newbie users that don't know how to ask a question and think a screenshot of their text editor is good enough is another.  Concerns that cannot easily be dismissed as irrelevant so there isn't much point to this question.  Earn enough rep and you can post anywhere without this restriction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

10 reputation is just a base line to avoid spam and isn't overly complicated to get. This isn't something that should be changed.

While it can be frustrating to have both links and pictures count towards the restriction, understand that nothing is stopping you from posting links or links towards pictures as raw text (or as a comment).

Any user with high enough reputation can edit your question and include the links or images if they are useful. (Something I do when I notice such a case)

Comment: You are wrong. The system also prevents just posting links e.g. like this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247739/understanding-likelihood-function-of-multiple-variables-kingma-et-al-2014. 
(I don't know if removing the `http` would help, but...)
Now that you said that you are willing to do these edits, could you do me a solid on [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247739/understanding-likelihood-function-of-multiple-variables-kingma-et-al-2014)?

Comment: @TokeFaurby seems like someone beat me to it. Fair enough for your point that the system notices raw text links, however you can modify the link a bit and it should work and/or add it as a comment like you did in that post. A while back I posted  an answer (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314517/a-step-towards-stopping-spammers/314533#314533)  regarding this issue. You can read on it a bit. It was refused because it would only add more work under review.