# Review audits using real links from real companies

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

While reviewing Late Answers, I stumbled across the following:

[image: An answer with a link to a blog and one line of text saying "this works".]

I understand why, during the review, this answer should be flagged as "Not an answer" or "Spam, because it's a link-only answer (if the link becomes invalid, then the answer will have 0 value); the "Spam" would make sense if the person was working for that company (which wasn't the case according to searching the people working in that firm in LinkedIn).

Still, I was wondering. Considering that if we go to the link given in that audit - https://krakensystems.co/blog/2020/custom-users-using-django-rest-framework - and it's a valid link from a specific firm, could this be seen as publicity?

If it wasn't for this particular case, I wouldn't have known such a firm exists, let alone that they're publishing content related with the Django REST Framework (which is something I work with).

I understand if Stack Overflow reutilizes answers that were given by real people and then afterwards closed (couldn't find other valid explanation to why this review audit showed up like this). Yet, this can give space to free publicity too - create an account, answer a question with link and wait for it to show up occasionally. The target users of this type of publicity would be users with good enough rep in Stack Overflow to be able to review content (plus others that see before it's closed). If by any chance it doesn't get closed, then the link will be here and might count positively for ranking in search engines.

A solution for this would be to use mocked links instead, but that could make things easier for reviewers (which at my sight would be ok - not that I want to increase review count (don't really need it)).

Comment: wonder if you are aware that posts older than 30 days are [excluded from audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398925/839601). This mean if someone wanted to use these to drive spam they would have to find a way to reliably remake it every 30 days

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Yet, this can give space to free publicity too - create an account, answer a question with link and wait for it to show up [in review as an audit] occasionally.

I think this is the core part of your question but it is somewhat lost in the middle of everything else.

Short answer is no, this is probably not a valuable form of advertising and designing a complicated fake link system is not worth the effort for several reasons

- Most reviews, including Audits, are only shown to a handful of users.
- Posts used as audits cannot be [more than 30 days old](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398925/839601).
- Not every bad answer is selected as an audit.

The chances are far more likely that the user would see a large number of flagged answers, and start tripping the spam prevention triggers or at least catch the eye of a moderator.

You also mentioned improving the search engine ranking.  That won't happen as most links posted on Stack Overflow have "nofollow" added (see: [Links nofollow and dofollow on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291005/250725)) so it really won't help with SEO.

And finally - substituting the link with a fake link is going to have an negative impact on reviews.  A fake link leading no where might be reviewed differently than a good link on a link only answer.  The former is probably going to start getting delete votes right away because it has no value anymore.  The latter might get some comments to improve the answer first before the delete votes start piling up.

Comment: gnat mentioned in a comment to the question something valuable that could be added to this answer to improve its value.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 i tried to be generic in case the logic changes with the "only shown to a handful of users".  But I can add it

Answer (score 5):

We want people to be able to recognize spam, not just audits (and not just in the review queue). We also want people to check to make sure a link goes where it says it's going and mocked links would prevent that. I've seen people put links in posts with claims they point to official documentation when they actually go to some random 3rd party site. (There was one suggested edit that claimed to fix a broken link to the official docs but actually changed a working link to point to some site that had copied the official docs very poorly.)

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of review is to confirm that content *as shown on the site* is acceptable by the rules. Using any sort of mock links will prevent this validation as one will not be able to distinguish valid content (that includes text and links) from random garbage/spam.

Right now there is no way on Stack Overflow to specify that post is spam *because of the link* - it very well could be that link is legitimate, but text subtly advertises "free Rolex watches". In this case, replacing a link with an obvious advertisement like free-porn.com would defeat the goal of teaching the reviewer to look at both links and content.

I don't think there is much concern if a dozen people will see a link to spam (or otherwise inappropriate content) in a review - how many people disable junk filters and go into junk mail to check out every link there? Worrying that reviewers will instantly buy into whatever is advertised on a post with huge "LIKELY SPAM" banner is a bit of a stretch for me.

Comment: Alexei Levenkov when hunting for spam the majority of the one's I find with research was basically using the user name profile and then compare with the LinkedIn page of the company (trying to find someone with that specific name is working there) or if the person has the same domain in the SO's profile URL.